# only else condition is executing in mysql using stored procedures during insert or update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my table schema 
`MariaDB [a1]> show create table bad_numbers_final;
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------
| Table             | Create Table
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------
| bad_numbers_final | CREATE TABLE bad_numbers_final (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  phone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  phone_count varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,phone)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126956 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------`
Now I want to insert a `phone` if that same number exists in the table then it just increase the `phone_count` otherwise add a new row in the table . So for that I use a `stored procedure` and write in it 
`BEGIN IF ('phone'='10083121224') THEN UPDATE bad_numbers_final SET phone_count= phone_count+10 WHERE 'phone'='10083121224' ;
ELSE INSERT INTO bad_numbers_final (phone,phone_count) VALUES ('10083121224',10);END IF;END`
But when I execute this procedure it always insert a new row in the table in place of increasing the `phone_count` because the value of`phone` which I'm inserting that value is already in the table so it just have to increase the `phone_count` but its not doing so. Please give any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your quotes (`'...'`) are incorrect in your `if`. Use the same format as in your `where`.

Comment: 'phone'=10083121224 in this condition phone is variable or constant? if constant then how can you compare if variable then why single quotes

Comment: Now is it write? But when I remove inverted comma from `phone` in `IF` condition then it shows error about `unknown column phone in field list`.

Comment: `'10083121224'` is a string and `10083121224` is a number. What kind of field is "phone"? Is it a varchar or an int field? The people above are referring to the quote marks round the _data_, not the column name. If you try to write a WHERE clause to match an integer to a string it will not match anything. You need to use the correct data type to match the data type of your column.

Comment: the datatype of `phone` is `varchar`

Comment: So in that case `'phone'=10083121224` can never be true, because the value in the phone field is not an integer. `'phone'='10083121224'` is likely to be what you need.

Comment: I've done this but still it is just inserting a new row.

Comment: I've just noticed another thing... I'm not sure if I understand this part: `IF ('phone'='10083121224')`...you appear to be comparing two strings to each other...two strings which clearly are not the same as each other and can never be equal. Did you mean `IF (phone='10083121224')`? So it compares it to the input variable called `phone`?

Comment: yes, I am comparing the value of `phone` with this value`10083121224`. If this condition satisfies than `update` query should execute otherwise `select` query execute.

Comment: So, did you get my point? What happens if you change your code as I've suggested?

Comment: No please clarify yourself that what exactly you want from my side.  Because I've tried all possible things.

Comment: I said you should try changing it to `IF (phone='10083121224')` so that it tries to compare the string to the variable named `phone` instead of the literal string `'phone'`. Sorry I thought that was clear from my comment. You didn't post your whole stored procedure but I assume you've got a variable called `phone`, yes? Or are you actually wanting to SELECT from the table to find out if the row already exists?

Answer (score 1):

1. In `'phone'='10083121224'` you are comparing two different strings. You should compare phone='10083121224'.
2. Also, `phone_count` is a `varchar(255)`. No. It should be a number (int
   or whatever) It doesnt make sense as `varchar`.You would concatenate "10" as a string this way. So if you had "0" before, after, you will have "010" and then "01010" and so on.

Then you can do this:

```
UPDATE bad_numbers_final SET phone_count= phone_count+10 WHERE phone='10083121224' ;
```

Where instead of '10083121224' my guess is that you will need to place a parameter for the procedure.
Also perhaps you want to change the phone datatype as number as well

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer of my own question i.e. I've done some changes in my `if` condition i.e.
`BEGIN
    IF (select phone from bad_numbers_final WHERE phone='10083121224') THEN 
      UPDATE bad_numbers_final SET phone_count= phone_count+10 WHERE phone='10083121224';
       ELSE INSERT INTO bad_numbers_final (phone,phone_count) VALUES ('10083121224',10);

    END IF;
    END`
the problem is that  my `if` condition isn't working because it is not getting from where the field `phone` is coming and it is just about to insert one `sub query` inside the `if` condition and here it is working fine and thank you for all of your suggestions.